# Не импортирует базу данных

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу импортировать файл в базу данных. Выдает такую ошибку в чем проблема? Файл с расширением .sql.gz

Comment: Вангую что вы не разжали архив...

Comment: Тут вот в чем проблема расширение линусовское а я с винды сижу

Comment: Расширение архива, проблемы тут нет.

Comment: а каким способом можно разжать архив? БД вордпресовское

Comment: Вы, конечно, не поверите, но архиватором! 7z например, неплохо справляется...

Comment: Можете расписать поподробней

Comment: Вы не умеете пользоваться архиватором?!

Comment: Мне 7z пишет "Не возможно открыть файл как gzip архив. Это не архив"

Comment: Это странно... Но без файла, боюсь, это будет гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Как я могу переслать его вам?

Comment: Файлообменник и ссылка, может еще кто что подскажет...

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/68Nze

Comment: Есть подозрение что архив битый: если удалить первые три байта, 7zip начинает его опознавать, но говорит что данные обрываются.

Comment: не надо ничего разжимать, это при импорте само делается, как и при экспорте.

Comment: тогда почему не импортируется?

Comment: @teran попробуйте у себя импортировать, есть подозрение что архив битый...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а чего пробовать то? сказали ведь что 7z не открывает. странно, конечно, что первые 3 байта удалять надо, ладно бы обрывался на середине. но лишнее в начале как то странновато. у меня 7z  тоже не открывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось, всем спасибо за содействие. Причина была в битом файле